How to clear all routes and push new one with new state [go_router]
When looking for on how to clear all routes and replace with a new one, all the solutions propose something like this
  void clearStackAndReplace(String path, Object? extra) {
    while (canPop() == true) {
      pop();
    }
    pushReplacement(path, extra: extra);
  }

But pushReplacement is preseving the state of the new route, and I don't want this, since I have some code on the initState method of the new route that I want to run.
How can I do this?

What about Navigator.popUntil(context, ModalRoute.withName('/login'));?
here the reference

You can write a function to pop every route, and push a new one when it's empty, something likw this:
void clearAndNavigate(String path) {
  while (getGoRouter().canPop() == true) {
  getGoRouter().pop();
}
  getGoRouter().pushReplacement(path);
}

getGoRouter is an instance of GoRouter

it's exactly what i wrote in the post that is not working

Could you please provide full code, so we can help you more>
